# How to save scikit-learn classifiert objects?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

How can I save multiple scikit-learn objects in a for-loop, for example:
1) LogisticRegression()
2) KNeighborsRegressor()

My code looks like this:

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
# save the model to disk
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

In this example I save each model on disk. How can I save multiple models in memory without saving? Can I do this with dictionary or lists?

Comment: Please explain more clearly as to what you want to do? What do you mean by saving in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a dict.

To save it to disk:

```
my_classifiers = {'logit': '<trained_logit_here>',
                  'KNN' : '<trained_KNN_here>'
                  }
pickle._dump(my_classifiers, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Then to load them:

```
loaded_classifiers = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
logit_model = loaded_classifiers['logit']
knn_model = loaded_classifiers['KNN']
```

You can later used them:

```
results = logit_model.predict(X)
```